# How to create a random array from a list, each value in the array is not duplicate?

Tags: python

My question is I have a list from 0 - 17 and I want to create a 7 value array in random, in which each value in the array is not duplicate in python?

Comment: Does the array contain duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
random.shuffle(lst)
lst[:7]
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.sample)

```
In [22]: L
Out[22]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

In [23]: random.sample(L, 7)
Out[23]: [6, 7, 2, 16, 10, 0, 3]
```